# Linux QT Creator C++: How to link with $$HOME?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, qt-creator, home-directory

I start a programm which includes a library (IDA) in
`/home/MYUSERNAME/EB/IDA/Earlybite/`

The library IDA has two folders:
`/home/MYUSERNAME/EB/IDA/IDA/Includes/ (for h-file)`
`/home/MYUSERNAME/EB/IDA/IDA/Libs/ (for so-files)`

This is the linking which works:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../IDA/Libs/ -Wl,-rpath=$$PWD/../IDA/Libs/ -lIDA -ldl -lpthread -lrt
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../IDA/Includes/
```

The problem is that PWD only shows the path in which Earlybite starts. In this case
`/home/MYUSERNAME/EB/IDA/Earlybite/`, but if the programm starts e.g. in   `/home/MYUSERNAME/EB/IDA/` ...the linking will not work.

So I tried to link with the HOME environment variable. E.g.

```
LIBS += -L$$HOME/EB/IDA/IDA/Libs/ -Wl,-rpath=$$HOME/EB/IDA/IDA/Libs/ -lIDA -ldl -lpthread -lrt
INCLUDEPATH += $$HOME/EB/IDA/IDA/Includes/
```

But this do not work.

I also tried

```
LIBS += -L/home/$$USER/EB/IDA/IDA/Libs/ -Wl,-rpath=/home/$$USER/EB/IDA/IDA/Libs/ -lIDA -ldl -lpthread -lrt
INCLUDEPATH += /home/$$USER/EB/IDA/IDA/Includes/
```

But this do not work, too. 
(I've also tried every try with a single $ and with two $ symbols...)

Comment: With $$HOME: libIDA not found, ida.h: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I just remembered that you can use `$$(HOME)` which will read environment variable during qmake execution, so you just need to add `()` around HOME. Using `$_PRO_FILE_PWD_` is still a good practice, but the last options is a workaround rather than straightforward solution I think.

---

You can try and use `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_`, this variable points to `.pro` file location, and create path relative to project file. Also check [qmake Variables](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file-pwd) for additional references.

Or you can do:

```
HOME = $$system(echo $HOME)
message($$HOME)
LIBS += -L$$HOME ...
```

About `$$system` [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command)

Comment: I had a look on the site where your link points to and it seems that $$HOME will never work... (confirm?).
HOME can't be found there.
I also tried message($$HOME) = "" (in variations)
Only message($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_) and message($$PWD) gives back a valid value.
$$HOME/... will never work, yes?

Comment: @Earlybite Yes, but take a look at my edit to answer.

Comment: @Earlybite yes it was a trick, I used system call to get $HOME variable from terminal. But I found one more solution, check it out.

Comment: hadn't known that the pro-file can be edit like this!
And $$HOME has been created by this, yes?
And hadn't known that it is possible to get a message...
Three useful parts. Thanks!
BTW: How can i add @Name?

Comment: @Earlybite Yes you can create your own variables in .pro files. You should check the QMake documentation if you're curious to know more.